# Angular - Not able to respond to the route

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

When i hit the url `http://localhost:8000/something` it redirects me to `login`, why?

Master template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="csrf_token" ng-init="csrf_token='<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>'">


</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    {{ HTML::script("js/ang/main.js") }}


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});


app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/something', {
            templateUrl: 'angular_templates/all-timelines.html',
            controller: 'timelinesCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });

});


app.controller('timelinesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

all-timelines.html

```
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Do u mean http://localhost:8000/#something?

Comment: @allenhwkim No `localhost:8000/something`.. i just tried localhost:8000/#something and it worked. Thank you. Does that mean that angular will only respond to urls after the hashtag?

Comment: Actually it did not work.. Using localhost:8000/#something just shows up my homepage..

Comment: unless you activate pushstate, u need to use hash tag. i.e.   `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` Also make it sure that your controller is working fine with template. Unless you provide a code, I can only help you with my guess.

Comment: @allenhwkim setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` worked for me, thank you! Does this mean it will only work on browsers that support html5? Is there a sensible fallback?

Comment: a good question, don't know about fallback. please google it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses hash routes to differentiate between client-side routing and server-side routing. As allenhwkim said in the comments above, `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` will allow you to route with Angular without using hash routes, but this will only work on modern browsers. Your app won't break on older browsers though; they'll just fall back to hash routes.

For example, with `html5Mode` on, you should be able to route to `localhost:8000/something` and see your expected Angular view. On an older browser though, you'll have to navigate to `localhost:8000/#/something`.

See the section on [Hashbang and HTML5 Mode](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) in the official Developer Guide.